# Как изменить код, чтобы он прошел тест на время?

Tags: python, numpy, статистика

Код не проходит по времени в тестирующей системе.
Сам код(необходимо найти скользящее взвешенное среднее):

```
import numpy as np

with open("input.txt", 'r') as fin:
    n, m = map(int, fin.readline().split()) # 1 < n < 10e5, 2 < m < 16
    w = list(map(int, fin.readline().split())) # m values
    y = np.array(list(map(float, fin.readline().split()))) # n values

s = sum(w)
if n < m:
    ans = y
else:
    ans = [sum(y[i: i+m] * w) / s for i in range(n-m+1)]

with open("output.txt", 'w') as fout:
    print(*ans, file=fout)
```

Comment: А не надо три раза читать с диска одно и то же. Надо прочитать один раз в переменную и с ней работать

Comment: В одну переменную все подряд прочитать? Странно это

Comment: Что же в этом странного? У вас ОЧЕНЬ медленная операция повторяется три раза. Код не проходит по времени, но ускорение кода вам кажется странным.

Answer (score 0):

Вы выполняете чтение файла 3 раза, это крайне медленная операция.
Лучше считать один раз, сохранить в переменную и использовать ее.

А ещё у вас две строки после with идентичны

Comment: Сейчас придёт автор и скажет "странно это".

Comment: Считал один раз, но все равно не проходит. Видимо с алгоритмом проблемы